Windows Terminal Server Gateway Installation - Unable to Create Self Signed Certificate
I am trying to install a Windows Terminal Services Gateway role on a server with existing TS Connection Broker role. It shows an error message saying
Failed:
Unable to create the self-signed certificate on . The error is 2147944153.
The role is installed but TS Gateway is not added to the configuration. I have a SSL certificate for the server - but the installation does not have any option to select the SSL.
Trying to add SSL to Connection Broker also gives an error saying certificate was not installed on some servers.
Tried uninstalling everything and installed again - but same results.
Thanks,
Rahul
